# Paging doesn't work if QLPreviewController inside UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller, qlpreviewcontroller

I have a `UIPageViewController` with a `.scroll` transition style. My goal is to add a `QLPreviewController` as a child, but in this case a scroll doesn't work and I can't do a paging from one vc to another.

I've wanted to play with `gestureRecognizers`, but this array is empty

> Only populated if transition style is
>   'UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl'.

Any ideas? :(

Comment: Does the QLPreviewController that you add to the page view controller have only one item in its dataSource, or multiple ones? The latter would be a strange use case and something that probably isn't supported. If you only have one item in the dataSource, make sure to file a radar at bugreport.apple.com — ideally with a sample project.

Comment: @Raffael yes, only a one item

Comment: @Raffael I don't know about bugreport really - the official doc says that this vc supports to be pushed to a navigation or being presented modally. There's nothing about page controller.